# Can't get rid of margin beneath CSS sticky footer

Tags: css, margin, sticky-footer

I'm using the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) technique described here, and have it sort of working.

Problem is, in most of my pages it ads an extra 20px margin or padding at the very bottom, and I can't locate where that comes from.

- [Here it is **without** the margin](http://preview.universalfavourite.com.au/kmj-j012/product-listing.html).
- [Here it is **with** the margin](http://preview.universalfavourite.com.au/kmj-j012/details.html).

In the how-to it says that some extra margins might get inherited from other elements. But I'm not able to hunt down the offender. Can anybody see what I've done different on the two example pages, or better yet, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ui-datepicker { display:none } ?

(it's the hidden datepicker div at the bottom. you have to hide it someway and check that it still works afterwards)

Comment: I had already checked for that. But upon further investigation it turns out you are right.